# Is the Mortarboard badge broken?

Tags: support, badges

I'm not complaining, but I think the [Mortarboard](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/mortarboard) badge is broken. I hit the rep cap yesterday and the day before, but didn't get the badge either time.

Is something busted or am I just being harebrained?

Comment: in your profile page / rep tab, check box "show removed posts" to make sure that none of yesterday upvotes was on a removed post (if this happened and badge award script run after removal, you'd be not eligible despite rep cap)

Comment: No @gnat. There was a hot network question that most of it came from. I didn't really want to link it here, but here it is. Definitely not removed. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/322724

Comment: right, and I just re-checked your rep tab myself: it shows qualifying rep for _two_ days, yesterday and 2 days ago. Really strange that badge wasn't awarded

Comment: Yeah. I don't really care about the badge, but it does seem odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I'm showing that you [already have the badge](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/mortarboard?userid=142319), earned March 4, 2015.  Mortarboard, along with its successors, Epic and Legendary, are single-award badges.

To see your progress towards Epic and Legendary, you can track them in your user profile!

Also, nice answer about events :)